# No compilation error when for generic funciton when object types do not match

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, typescript-generics

Consider the following generic function which does nothing:

```
const typed = <T>(fields: T) => {}
```

Then we define the folliwng type and variable:

```
type Simple = { a: string };

const fields = { a: "", b: "" };
```

The following is running properly

```
typed<Simple>(fields);
```

but this causes a compilation error:

```
typed<Simple>({ a: "", b: "" });
```

In both cases, the input type is the same and yet the second example fails (as it should). Why the first cases work though?

*Typescript version: **3.5.3***

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgExgXhgHgCoD4AKAMwEtkAbVCALhlwEpN8YBvAXwFgAoHhFGAGVSAW0QVkmNjACGdaACdSYAOYx2Abh6hIsMpWpTWsugCJTAGhgAjM6fVbe3APTO4AC1IQYoMaQkQfEho2MJiEkT6VBAMjjyuHl4+MgCuEMjevoj+MlCk4DDICgogCkEoqKGi4shExnIw5la2jfbssTxAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `object literals` as parameter, they undergo excess property checks - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks.

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property
>   checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as
>   arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target
>   type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error:

Only known properties can be passed through object literal. The `simple` type only have property `a`, however object literal have additional property `b` along with `a`.

Solution -

`typed<Simple>({ a: "", b: "" } as Simple);`

Comment: Actually, your solution is the opposite of my goal; I want `typed<Simple>(fields);` to cause a compilation error.

Comment: @skay- I answered the reason for compilation error. `typed<Simple>(fields)` won't cause error. The compiler check for required properties and also allow for additional properties too. In your example, the fields already have property `a` from `simple` type with additional property `b`. See - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#our-first-interface.

Comment: I know and I have marked your answer as accepted. I am just making a seperate side-note here that I want to force the compiler to result to compilation error in either case.